# How can an ID be passed from one router to another in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In a node.js app I'm building when a user is registered, I will redirect them to a cars page where they can add a car. The cars table has a user_id column that references the users id column.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.body.firstname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    const newUser = { name, email, password };

    res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, function(err, row) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/cars');
        }
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pass along the newly inserted id in my redirect. Is this possible? Will this be the best way to handle such?

Comment: @manikantgautam This question is about NodeJS, not Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.body.firstname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    const newUser = { name, email, password };

    res.locals.connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, function(err, row) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            res.redirect('/cars/?id=' + res.insertedId);
        }
    });
});
```

acess in router with

```
req.query.id;
```

Comment: This line `let res.id` keeps throwing error
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token
Any reason why? I was able to get my code to work by using `var user_id = row.insertedId` though.

Comment: @Mena yes i dont actually know the keyword thats why i put just id.